# Having trouble with create method in CommentsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my current Create method in CommentsController

```
def create
   @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
   @comment = @place.comments.create(comment_params)
   @comment.user = current_user
 if @comment.save
  redirect_to place_path(@place)
 else
  render "comments/_form"
 end
end
```

I was told by someone that this hits the database twice. Upon checking the logs, this is the result:

```
Started GET "/places/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 15:01:47 -0800
Processing by PlacesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
Place Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "places".* FROM "places"  WHERE       "places"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."place_id" = ?  [["place_id", 9]]
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ?    LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ?   LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ?    LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (8.0ms)
Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (2.7ms)
Rendered places/show.html.erb within layouts/application (73.3ms)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 200 OK in 532ms (Views: 529.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

So obviously, I don't want to be inefficient in my code.

This is what the person suggested instead:

```
comment_params[:user_id] = current_user.id
if @places.comments.create(comment_params)
   .....
else 
    ....
end
```

So ... I rewrote the Create method to this:

```
 def create
   @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
   @comment = @place.comments.create(comment_params)
   comment_params[:user_id] = current_user.id
  if @places.comments.create(comment_params)
   redirect_to place_path(@place)
  else
   render "comments/_form"
  end
 end
```

Upon the rewritten Create method, I keep getting this error when I try to leave a comment: `undefined method comments for nil:NilClass`

Help me to understand how to rewrite this Create method correctly, please?

**SideNote - Not sure if it's relevant if yes, please address it, if no, please ignore**

Upon checking the last comment in the rails console, I was startled to see that the user_id is *nil*, whereas for place, it's not.

Place belongs to User
Comment belongs to User

User has many of both Place and Comment

Comment: You have a typo there. It probably should be \@place not \@places in your if statement.

Comment: @AndreasGnyp, thanks for pointing that out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `create` twice, which would result in the comment being posted twice, which is probably not what you have intended.

The first time you call create, it has no user_id assigned, that's the reason the `user_id` is set to null in the database (hint: use a presence validation on the `user_id` in your comment model).

The second time you call create you call it on `@places` instead of `@place` (typo). This causes your nil error.

Here is another way to solve your problem:

```
 def create
   @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
   @comment = @place.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.user_id = current_user.id

   if @comment.save(comment_params)
     redirect_to place_path(@place)
   else
     render "comments/_form"
   end
 end
```

The difference is, that we first "build" a comment without creating it, but it will be filled with the ID of the place etc.

In a next step we add the current user's id and then we call save on the object, which hits the database.

Comment: hey, just noticed the first line in your answer about the comment being posted twice. It's not actually. But your answer helped. It's just the trying to wrap my mind around the code, and being good at it is driving me crazy, you know? =)